# Generate YAML format response in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I want to generate YAML format type response using Spring boot. can you please help me here to get it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you have the following dependency on the classpath:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then define your own `HttpMessageConverter`:

```java
class MappingJackson2YamlHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    MappingJackson2YamlHttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(objectMapper, MediaType.parseMediaType("application/x-yaml"));
    }
}
```

Expose it as a Spring [`@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html):

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonYamlConfig {

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2YamlHttpMessageConverter yamlHttpMessageConverter() {

        YAMLMapper mapper = new YAMLMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        return new MappingJackson2YamlHttpMessageConverter(mapper);
    }
}
```

And finally configure your controller method to produce YAML:

```java
@GetMapping(produces = "application/x-yaml")
public ResponseEntity<Foo> getFoo() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sever start up Failed to instantiate [com/test/api/config.MappingJackson2YamlHttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'yamlHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TSFBuilder

Comment: @Vbr You seem to be missing some dependency from Jackson core.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cassiomolin , it is working after add pom dependency for Jackson core.